# Reversing a flat array of coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates, reverse

I have a path of (x,y) coordinates as a flat array, like this:

```
[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, ...]
```

To flip it from clockwise to counterclockwise, I need to reverse it pairwise: x3,y3,x2,y2,x1,y1.  The following works and is pretty fast to boot:

```
var a = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3'];
for (var i = 0; i < (a.length/2); i = i + 2) {
    var x = a[i];
    var y = a[i+1];
    a[i] = a[a.length - 2 - i];
    a[i+1] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
    a[a.length - 2 - i] = x;
    a[a.length - 1 - i] = y;
};
```

But is there a more elegant approach?  I played with `splice` for a bit, but it returns the spliced items as an array and wants them back as arguments, which breaks things:

```
for (var i = 0; i < (a.length/2); i = i + 2) {
    a.splice(i, 0, a.splice(a.length-2-i, 2)); // doesn't work
};
```

Although I suppose you could work around that with creative use of `apply`, but ergh.

Filtering in an array of x's and y's, calling reverse on each and splicing them back together seems possible, but it's pretty verbose in JS and probably a lot less efficient.

*Edit*: The arrays are of arbitrary length and may contain hundreds of thousands of pairs, so speed and memory usage are important.

Comment: I like the first approach. If you're worried about readability, extracting the loop body into `swapPair(array, i, j)` would be nice.

Comment: Multi dimensional array would help I guess. You can use a 3x2 array and then swap the first and third rows when you need to flip.

Comment: Sorry, this is a one-off operation, and the data both comes in and has to go out in the flat format given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little cleaner if you use two counters, one from the start, and the other from the end.

```
var a = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3'];

for (var i = 0, j = a.length-2; i < j; i+=2, j-=2) {
    var t1 = a[i],
        t2 = a[i+1];
    a[i]   = a[j];
    a[i+1] = a[j+1];
    a[j]   = t1;
    a[j+1] = t2;
}
```

---

Or with a little hackery, you can shorten it a little.

```
var a = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3'];

for (var i = 0, j = a.length-2; i < j; i+=2, j-=2) {
    a[ i ] = [a[ j ], a[ j ] = a[ i ]][0];
    a[i+1] = [a[j+1], a[j+1] = a[i+1]][0];
}
```

---

And let's not forget about destructuring assignment. This is coming in ECMAScript 6, but will work right now in Firefox.

```
var a = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3'];

for (var i = 0, j = a.length-2; i < j; i+=2, j-=2) {
    [a[i], a[j], a[i+1], a[j+1]] = [a[j], a[i], a[j+1], a[i+1]];
}
```

---

One other possibility would be to first reverse the entire array, then reverse the pairs.

```
var a = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3'];

a.reverse();

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=2) {
    var t  = a[i];
    a[i]   = a[i+1];
    a[i+1] = t;
}
```

Probably slower, but certainly cleaner.

---

Or using a separate array for the result can eliminate temporary variables.

```
var a = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3'];
var b = new Array(a.length);

for (var i = 0, j = a.length-2; i <= j; i+=2, j-=2) {
    b[j]   = a[i],
    b[j+1] = a[i+1];
    b[i]   = a[j];
    b[i+1] = a[j+1];
}
```

Initializing the Array with its full length can give a performance boost in modern implementations.

Comment: +1 for your first and third answers (even though I can't use that yet, this has to be cross-browser).  The second is a bit too hacky for my liking.

Comment: @jpatokal: Yeah, I wouldn't use the second one either. Just thought I'd throw it out there as a novel approach.

Answer (score 1):

Cookie monster's algorithm actually becomes faster, more readable, and DRYer if you introduce a swapping helper function:

```
function swap(ary, x, y) {
  var t = ary[x];
  ary[x] = ary[y];
  ary[y] = t;
}

function helperDualCounterPairwiseReverse(coords) {
  var a = coords.slice(0);
  for (var i = 0, j = a.length-2; i < j; i+=2, j-=2) {
    swap(a, i, j);
    swap(a, i+1, j+1);
  };
  return a;
}
```

Here's another readable, but less performant variation:

```
function semanticPairwiseReverse(coords) {
  var prev, reversed = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < coords.length/2 + 2; i = i + 2) {
    reversed.unshift(coords[i], coords[i + 1]);
  };
  return reversed;
}
```

If you're only dealing with 3D data sets and you're overly concerned with performance, you may want to consider a "dumb" approach wherein you hard code the swaps:

```
function dumbPairwiseReverse(coords) {
  var reversed = coords.slice(0); // Duplicates the coordinate list
  reversed[0] = coords[4]; reversed[4] = coords[0];
  reversed[1] = coords[5]; reversed[5] = coords[1];
  return reversed;
}
```

Here are some benchmarks of the above along with the other presented solutions: http://jsperf.com/pairwise-reverse/5

Comment: +1 for readability and the benchmarks, but as now noted, the arrays may be *really* long so performance matters.

Comment: Tweaked your benchmark to test a N=100000 array: http://jsperf.com/pairwise-reverse/3  @cookie monster's dual counter approach beats mine by around 14%, while the semantic reverse is *way*  slower (4 ops/s, vs. >2600 for the fastest).

Comment: Wowza. `unshift` seems to be [absurdly expensive](http://jsperf.com/unshift-vs-push-empty-vs-monster). Introducing a helper function to cookie monsters dual counter seems to be a winner in terms of both performance and readability.